# Adding 90 days to created date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm grabbing the first day of the next quarter as `StartDate`. How can I add 90 days to it. The below is gives me invalid column error for StartDate within `EndDate`.

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
    DATEADD(day, 90, MAX(StartDate)) as EndDate
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

column

```
Time_Stamp
-----------
2014-06-04 16:01:14.000
2014-06-04 15:55:33.000
2014-06-04 15:45:05.000
2014-06-04 15:36:15.000
2014-06-04 15:00:34.000
2014-06-04 14:35:24.000
2014-06-04 14:04:50.000
2014-06-04 13:46:55.000
2014-06-04 13:23:57.000
2014-06-04 11:27:51.000
```

Just for refernce I found this which was very useful:
http://zarez.net/?p=2484

So ended up with something like this:

```
SELECT 
     --Returns first day of next quarter
     DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
     --Returns last day of next quarter
     DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +2, 0)) as EndDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

Comment: Please type `DAY`/`QUARTER` instead of this lazy `dd`/`qq` shorthand. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql query doesn't know of column alias in the select.  It is a self referencing error.  The select statement creates the alias so it can't itself use the alias.  The only statement to run after select is order by, where you can use an alias.

I would reuse your logic to prevent needing a subquery.  Since ninety days is just another quater, change 1 to 2 and add another quarter to your Time Stamp.

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 2, 0) as EndDate
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's invalid because StartDate is alias for your date calculation. You can use alias only when you have results. In other words alias is available when you have dataset returned from server.

You can for example use subquery:

```
SELECT
  StartDate,
  DATEADD(day, 90, MAX(StartDate)) as EndDate
FROM (
  SELECT
     DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate
  FROM Survey
  WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
) DS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a derived column by name within the same query. You will have to add the same logic here.

```
SELECT
DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
DATEADD(day, 90, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0)) as EndDate
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

Not quite sure what you are trying to do with MAX in there so I just removed it.